Why won't PhpStorm install?
I use Ubuntu 24.04. In the App Center, the PhpStorm screen is displayed like this:

If I install via the terminal sudo snap install phpstorm --classic it says: - snap package "phpstorm" not found.

It looks like Jebtrains has banned downloading from Belarusian and Russian IP addresses. I managed to download it under VPN

Have you tried installing it with Jetbrains Toolbox: https://www.jetbrains.com/toolbox-app/
